# Filter data frame colum by variable name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
  pos.rank = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  neg.rank = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
```

I am trying to filter the data frame based on the values `1:3` in the `pos.rank` or `neg.rank` column, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- "neg.rank"
y <- "pos.rank"

df.x <- df[df[x] %in% 1:3, ]
df.y <- df[df[y] %in% 1:3, ]
```

But both `df.x` and `df.y` are empty.
When I run `df[x]` I get this output:

```
   neg.rank
1        10
2         9
3         8
4         7
5         6
6         5
7         4
8         3
9         2
10        1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsetting with `[` returns a dataframe, you need to use `[[` which will return a vector.

```
df[x] %in% 1:3
#[1] FALSE

df[[x]] %in% 1:3
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

To subset the data.

```
x <- "neg.rank"
y <- "pos.rank"
df[df[[x]] %in% 1:3 | df[[y]] %in% 1:3, ]

#   gene pos.rank neg.rank
#1     A        1       10
#2     B        2        9
#3     C        3        8
#8     H        8        3
#9     I        9        2
#10    J       10        1
```

If you want separate dataframes.

```
df.x <- df[df[[x]] %in% 1:3, ]
df.y <- df[df[[y]] %in% 1:3, ]
```

Comment: Can also use `$` for the same effect as `[[`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you using conditions on a data.frame without giving its column/vector location.  These will work

```
df.x <- df[df[x][,1] %in% 1:3, ]
df.y <- df[df[y][,1] %in% 1:3, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `,` during subsetting and make `df[,x]` instead of `df[x]` to get a *vector* instead of a *data.frame* to compare with `%in%`.

```
df.x <- df[df[,x] %in% 1:3,]
df.y <- df[df[,y] %in% 1:3, ]

df.x
#   gene pos.rank neg.rank
#8     H        8        3
#9     I        9        2
#10    J       10        1

df.y
#  gene pos.rank neg.rank
#1    A        1       10
#2    B        2        9
#3    C        3        8
```